# How to use Cast in Oracle sp

Tags: sql, oracle

in follwing "AND CAST(FLAGS AS BIGINT) & 1 = 1" how to write this for an Oracle sp we have to allow app to handle Oracle users as well.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [OGEN].[DBD_GET_STOCK_SUMMARY]
@FACILITY_KEY VARCHAR(1000),
@START_DATE DATETIME,
@END_DATE DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) COUNT, OGEN.DATEONLY(CREATED_ON) [DATE]
    FROM OGEN.NDC_M_FORMULARY


    WHERE OGEN.DATEONLY(CREATED_ON) BETWEEN OGEN.DATEONLY(@START_DATE) AND OGEN.DATEONLY(@END_DATE)
    AND FACILITY_KEY IN (SELECT VALUE FROM OGEN.COMMA_TO_TABLE(@FACILITY_KEY)) 
    **AND CAST(FLAGS AS BIGINT) & 1 = 1**
    GROUP BY OGEN.DATEONLY(CREATED_ON) 
END 


GO
```

Comment: I think you want the BITAND function . . . http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `BIGINT` , you can use  `NUMBER` or `BINARY_INTEGER` in oracle in following way...

```
CAST (FLAGS  AS NUMBER(19))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) count, trunc(CREATED_ON) "DATE"
  from NDC_M_FORMULARY
 where trunc(CREATED_ON) BETWEEN trunc(:startDate) AND trunc(:endDate)
   and FACILITY_KEY IN (select cast (regexp_substr(:facilityKey,'[^,]+', 1, level) as number)
                          from dual
                       connect by regexp_substr(:facilityKey, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
   and bitand(cast (flags as int), 1) = 1
 group by trunc(CREATED_ON)
```